# How to parse JSON to the tableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

Please give me advise, I can not figure out how to parse data in a table view properly. My goal is to make a tableView with all continents, not just with one "Africa" cell.

[image]

Here is my model:

```
struct ContinentRoot: Codable {
let links: ContinentMiddle 
}

struct ContinentMiddle: Codable {
let continentItems: [ContinentsResponse]
}

struct ContinentsResponse: Codable {
let name: String
let href: String
}
```

In ViewController I add tableView, continentsArray ([ContinentRoot]) and do some regular things for networking.
I guess that the problem may be here, because in the networking method everything seems normal:

```
private func getContinentsList() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.teleport.org/api/continents/") else { fatalError("URL failed")}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            guard let continent = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ContinentRoot.self, from: data) else { fatalError("DecodingError \(error!)") // REMEMBER: the highest struct
            }
            self?.continentsArray.append(continent)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return continentsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContinentsTableViewController", for: indexPath)
    let model = continentsArray[indexPath.row].links.continentItems[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.text = model
    return cell
}
```

In viewDidLoad() I call my methods:

```
getContinentList()
tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(ContinentsTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContinentsTableViewController")
    setupLayout()
```

Thank you so much for for attention!

Comment: It's not really clear what your precise objective is here, but it seems very unlikely that you want to use `indexPath.row` for both the index of `continentsArray` *and* `links.continentItems`

Comment: @jnpdx yes, you are right, I just try to realize how to get to name finally

Comment: Did you just change to use this index?
    let model = continentsArray[indexPath.section].links.continentItems[indexPath.row].name

Comment: what is continentsArray definition?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar var continentsArray = [ContinentRoot]()

Answer (score 0):

According to your attachment design:

if **continentsArray** is an array of **"ContinentRoot"** s.
and you want to show the links in the selected ContinentRoot you must first select it, and use it like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return selectedContinent.links.continentItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContinentsTableViewController", for: indexPath)
    let model = selectedContinent.links.continentItems[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.text = model
    return cell
}
```

if Not you must use your code and change this line:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContinentsTableViewController", for: indexPath)
    
let selectedIndex = .zero // or every index you want
    let model = continentsArray[indexPath.row].links.continentItems[selectedIndex].name
    cell.textLabel?.text = model
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but l don't understand how you get selectedContinent?

Comment: That is, my goal is to output a table with all continents, not just one cell

Comment: can you share your design and json model?

Comment: I add more information in my question

Comment: UI
`private func setupLayout() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }`

Comment: can you share your response model? such as a json?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is what you wanted from me, I hope that's json model:

`{
  "_links": {
    "continent:items": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/continents/geonames:AF/",
        "name": "Africa"
      },`

Comment: I'm not sure because of I can't see your complete jsonModel but try this:
"let selectedContinent = continentsArray[.zero]" in first solution I said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247269/discussion-between-maziar-saadatfar-and-maytime).